# create a sqlite database that can be access by all the application in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database created , and will be updated,  by the native code. What should I do to make it available to other Java **applications** which will only read the database? Will a ContentProvider be sufficient to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6cff1cf0e10e29?pli=1 you should use a ContentProvider:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

```
Content providers store and retrieve data and make it accessible to all applications. They're the only way to share data across applications; there's no common storage area that all Android packages can access
```

That tutorials are quite detailed.